# change PATH env variable on databricks

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables, databricks

I need to update my python path so that I can use python3 on databricks.

On databricks notebook:

```
  %sh
  echo $PATH

  /databricks/python2/bin:/databricks/python3/bin:/usr/local/sbin
```

Then, I run:

```
  %sh
  export PATH=/databricks/python3/bin:$PATH
```

But, I still got:

```
  %sh
  echo $PATH

  /databricks/python2/bin:/databricks/python3/bin:/usr/local/sbin
```

How can I change PATH? 
Also, when I created a cluster on databricks, the python version is 3.6 but why python2 is used ?

thanks

Comment: maybe it set new path only for this one execution of sh - you could run `export` and `echo` in the same cell to check it.

Comment: I created community account and when I check notebook (and cluster) it shows me only Python3. In `Clusters` it shows `"Runtime 6.1 (Scala 2.11, Spark 2.4.4) This Runtime version supports only Python 3."` Maybe you have to create new claster with different settings.

Comment: You are running your cluster with an outdated runtime environment. Is there any reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the offical document [`Cluster Configurations / Databricks Runtime / Python version`](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/configure.html#specify-python-version) of Databricks, it sounds like your current databricks cluster is created for Runtime 5.5 or below with Python 2, because the databricks runtime version above 5.5 only supports Python 3, as the figure below.

[image]

So if you only want to use Python 3 in databricks, you just need to create a cluster which runtime version above 5.5.

Or if you have to use Runtime 5.5, please create a new cluster to specify Python 2. Note: I tried to set the environment variable `PYSPARK_PYTHON` with the Python 3 path via `%sh export PYSPARK_PYTHON=....` on a existing running cluster, it do not work.